# Part of the citrus leaves are dull and dark graying

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, diseases, leaves, citrus

I did look up different diseases online but I'm having a hard time finding a match for these symptoms, the leaves with the dull color feel drier and not as smooth the the touch as regular normal leaves. Could someone identify the problem here please.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Spider mites, spray with soap and water